# Can't draw Histogram, 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r, histogram

I have a data file with this format:

```
Weight    Industry Type  
251,787   Kellogg  h  
253,9601  Kellogg  a  
256,0758  Kellogg  h  
....
```

I read the data and try to draw an histogram with this commands:

```
 ce <- read.table("file.txt", header = TRUE)

 we = ce[,1]
 in = ce[,2]
 ty = ce[,3]

hist(we)
```

But I get this error:

> Error en hist.default(we) : 'x' must be numeric.

What do I need to do in order to draw histograms for my three variables ?

Comment: Related post: [How to read in numbers with a comma as decimal separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123378)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because of the thousand separator, the data will have been read as 'non-numeric'. So you need to convert it:

```
 we <- gsub(",", "", we)   # remove comma
 we <- as.numeric(we)      # turn into numbers
```

and now you can do

```
 hist(we)
```

and other numeric operations.

Comment: A correction: it's not the thousand separator, it's the decimal point that in some countries is a comma. So it needs to be replaced by a point, not removed.

Comment: There is an argument `sep=""` to `read.table`, `read.csv`, ... that allows you to set this at the R level.

Answer (score 5):

Note that you could as well plot directly from `ce` (after the comma removing) using the column name :

```
hist(ce$Weight)
```

(As opposed to using `hist(ce[1])`, which would lead to the same "must be numeric" error.)

This also works for a database query result.

Comment: It helps for me! The data type is already dbl, but I cannot run something like hist(ce[,Weight]).

Answer (score 3):

Use the *dec* argument to set `","` as the decimal point by adding:

```
 ce <- read.table("file.txt", header = TRUE, dec = ",")
```

Comment: why does this make the data numeric?