# How to read in numbers with a comma as decimal separator?

Tags: r, csv, number-formatting

I have a series of CSV files where numbers are formatted in the european style using commas instead of decimal points, i.e. `0,5` instead of `0.5`.

There are too many of these files to edit them before importing to R. I was hoping there is an easy parameter for the `read.csv()` function, or a method to apply to the extracted dataset in order for R to treat the data as a number rather than a string.

Comment: You should provide a dummy data. This may be far more complicated problem, if your separators are also `,`. =/

Comment: Maybe you could try with `read.csv2`?

Comment: @Marek, that's right, if the separator is `;`, but one can set another separator string easily...

Answer (score 54, accepted):

When you check `?read.table` you will probably find all the answer that you need.

There are two issues with (continental) European csv files:

1. What does the `c` in csv stand for? For standard csv this is a `,`, for European csv this is a `;`
   `sep` is the corresponding argument in `read.table`
2. What is the character for the decimal point? For standard csv this is a `.`, for European csv this is a `,`
   `dec` is the corresponding argument in `read.table`

To read standard csv use `read.csv`, to read European csv use `read.csv2`. These two functions are just wrappers to `read.table` that set the appropriate arguments.

If your file does not follow either of these standards set the arguments manually.

Comment: there is no such thing as "European csv". You might refer to german/french,... number representation. However, there is no single/simple European csv :)

Comment: Can you instruct about how to read in rows where comma acts as a decimal separator and also as a field separator? Field values are delimited by double-quotes. I moved this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44855415/r-how-to-read-in-numbers-with-comma-as-a-dec-separator-a-field-separator-th).

Answer (score 13):

From `?read.table`:

```
dec     the character used in the file for decimal points.
```

And yes, you can use that for `read.csv` as well. (to me: no stupid, you cannot!)

Alternatively, you can also use

```
read.csv2
```

which assumes a "," decimal separator and a ";" for column separators.

Answer (score 4):

```
read.csv(... , sep=";")
```

Suppose this imported field is called "amount", you can fix the type in this way if your numbers are being read in as character:

```
d$amount <- sub(",",".",d$amount)
d$amount <- as.numeric(d$amount)
```

I have this happen to me frequently along with a bunch of other little annoyances when importing from excel or excel csv. As it seems that there's no consistent way to ensure getting what you expect when you import into R, post-hoc fixes seem to be the best method. By that I mean, LOOK at what you imported - make sure it's what you expected and fix it if it's not.

Comment: I like solution with `setAs` as in answers from [DWin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068705/processing-negative-number-in-accounting-format-in-r/5069649#5069649) and [Greg Snow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523126/how-to-read-a-csv-file-in-r-where-some-numbers-contain-commas/3611619#3611619)

Answer (score 3):

can be used as follow:

```
mydata <- read.table(fileIn, dec=",")

input file (fileIn):

D:\TEST>more  input2.txt

06-05-2014 09:19:38     3,182534        0

06-05-2014 09:19:51     4,2311          0
```

Answer (score 2):

Problems may also be solved if you indicate how your missing values are represented (na.strings=...). For example V1 and V2 here have the same format (decimals separated by "," in csv file), but since NAs are present in V1 it is interpreted as factor:

```
dat <- read.csv2("...csv", header=TRUE)
head(dat)

> ID x    time    V1    V2
> 1  1   0:01:00 0,237 0.621
> 2  1   0:02:00 0,242 0.675
> 3  1   0:03:00 0,232 0.398


dat <- read.csv2("...csv", header=TRUE, na.strings="---")
head(dat)

> ID x    time    V1    V2
> 1  1   0:01:00 0.237 0.621
> 2  1   0:02:00 0.242 0.675
> 3  1   0:03:00 0.232 0.398
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe

```
as.is=T
```

this also prevents to convert the character columns into factors

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the decimal character as a parameter (`dec = ","`):

```
# Semicolon as separator and comma as decimal point by default
read.csv2(file, header = TRUE, sep = ";", quote = "\"", dec = ",",
          fill = TRUE, comment.char = "", encoding = "unknown", ...)
```

More info on https://r-coder.com/read-csv-r/

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Brandon's answer above, which worked well for me (I don't have enough rep to comment):

If you're using

```
    d$amount <- sub(",",".",d$amount)
    d$amount <- as.numeric(d$amount)
```

don't forget that you may need `sub("[.]", "", d$amount, perl=T)` to get around the `.` character.

Comment: Couple of years later and you do have the reputation now - congrats on that.