# import large data from .txt file into matlab

Tags: matlab, large-data

I'm a newbie to MATLAB. I've a .txt file with 2 header lines and a total of 140000 rows and 6 columns. I want to extract only the first 116959 rows with any one column data of interest and store it as an vector. I want to use this column vector further for fft analysis. Like this I want to read multiple columns and store them as vectors.

```
Time        T_hor   T_ver   V_hor   V_ver   SPEED   
s       um  um  um  um  Hz  
39,000000   8,833   -15,43  -11,871 23,604  701,17  
39,000200   3,121   -22,78  -9,949  41,712  701,17  
39,000400   -8,012  -26,28  -4,317  33,790  701,17  
39,000600   -13,092 -20,22  8,343   20,630  701,17  
39,000800   -16,408 -5,27   6,869   5,680   701,17  
39,001000   -10,591 5,36    1,895   -0,005  701,17  
39,001200   2,016   -0,01   -7,054  6,786   701,17  
39,001400   8,622   -14,06  -11,581 20,998  701,17  
39,001600   4,279   -22,17  -10,002 39,791  701,17  
39,001800   -7,117  -25,70  -5,738  35,106  701,17  
39,002000   -12,697 -20,99  6,948   22,314  701,17  
39,002200   -16,355 -6,83   6,738   7,602   701,17  
39,002400   -11,960 5,68    2,079   0,469   701,17  
39,002600   0,463   2,10    -6,422  5,759   701,17  
39,002800   8,964   -11,91  -11,765 19,498  701,17
```

This is how the data looks like ( ignore commas(,) the data is in the German format which is equivalent to '39.0012'). I tried using importdata with space delimiters. But it gave me errors. The following is the code I used.

```
filename = 'Test_Data.txt';
delimiterIn = ' ';
headerlinesIn = 2;
A = importdata(filename,delimiterIn,headerlinesIn);   

for k = [3, 5] % Extracting 3rd and 5th column
   disp(A.colheaders{1, k})
   disp(A.data(:, k))
   disp(' ')
end
```

I get errors when using this method.I guess there is something more easy and logical I'm missing. Could someone shed some light on this.

Comment: A similar problem with dot and comma was discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204080/matlab-how-to-read-in-numbers-with-a-comma-as-decimal-separator

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I checked that code. Apart from the conversion. My question was "How to read and store as a single column vector"

Comment: `fread` would be the most efficient, but `importdata` is probably the easiest way to load and later to transform your data. It is however a little bit slow.

Comment: @c.colden when I use     fread it returns me a value '0'

Comment: I apologize, I meant `fscanf` - `fread` is only for binary files. Sorry once again. Please check http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html for more information

Comment: @c.Colden  Thanks for your reply. From the link you provided. I've a question. How do we read each column. I meant how to implement delimiter to extract only the column I need and store it in an vector.

Comment: If possible I would suggest you the following: Get rid of the spaces and replace them with commas and replace your commas with dots. Load this file as you did using `importdata` and now you can access the data very easy like you showed it in you example! Alternative also `dlmread`would work, too.

Comment: @C.Colden. I replaced commas with dots and imported the file using fopen. Now it works. However I'd issues with other functions.

Comment: If the error is something related, let me know. I will add my answer, if you don't mind accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible I would suggest you the following: Get rid of the spaces and replace them with commas and replace your commas with dots. Load this file as you did using `importdata` or alternatively `fread` or `dlmread`. Now you can access the data very easy as you showed it in your example.