# Error when calculating correlation

Tags: r

I have 2 columns of data with numerical values as follows which is tab delimited format:

```
Si1     Si2

8,99691 7,495936
7,7164173   8,092645
4,4428697   4,298263
7,4302206   7,189521
5,897344    5,316047
. 
.
.
```

To calculate correlation between these I wrote R code as follows:

```
int<-read.table("data.txt",sep="\t",head=TRUE)
attach(int)
cor(int$Si1,int$Si2)
```

But it shows error as follows:

```
Error in cor(int$Si1,int$Si2) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Can anybody tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Here's a question that deals with using commas as decimal separators - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123378/how-to-read-in-numbers-with-a-comma-as-decimal-separator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate a correlation between two vectors they must be numeric (numbers).  You have commas in your data and so they are not numeric.

Are they meant to be there?  This  works fine:

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
y<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
cor(x,y)

returns [1] 1
```

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to write `read.table("data.txt",sep="\t",header=TRUE, dec = ",")` at least. Your data has comma as a decimal separator. R assumes a period (.).