# R: Read in CSV decimal point and comma

Tags: r

Im a beginner, i want to read in a csv file with both . and , being a decimal separator. how can i do this in R. thanks

```
AllDataxx=read.csv("C:Sample.csv",
                  header=TRUE,sep=";",dec=", & .")
```

Comment: Maybe this helps ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123378/how-to-read-in-numbers-with-a-comma-as-decimal-separator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this out of the box I am afraid.
Of course what you can do is decide which you want say `.`, and use the `colClasses` argument to load the `,` columns as a `character`. Then you will use `gsub(pattern=`,`,replacement='.', x=yourColumnVector)` to change the `,` into `.` and `as.numeric` to cast the vector to `numeric`

```
DF = data.frame(a=c(1.1,1.3,1.4),b=c('1,1','1,3','1,6'))
DF
    a   b
1 1.1 1,1
2 1.3 1,3
3 1.4 1,6
str(DF)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: num  1.1 1.3 1.4
 $ b: chr  "1,1" "1,3" "1,6"
DF$b = as.numeric(gsub(',','.',DF$b))
DF
    a   b
1 1.1 1.1
2 1.3 1.3
3 1.4 1.6
```