# Histogram in R. Problem with Function hist()

Tags: r, histogram

I have csv file with ID and variable. It looks like this

```
    ID   V1
    1    0
    2   -0,12
    3    0,05
    ....
```

if I use hist(mydata$V1) I get an error message

```
Error in hist.default(mydata$V1) : 'x' must be numeric
```

But with variable ID (mydata$ID) it works. What is bad with variable V1, 0 at first place? Thanks!

Comment: We'd need a minimum reproducible example, and likely, your settings as well. To begin, what do you get when you type str(mydata)?

Answer (score 1):

> What is bad with variable V1, 0 at first place?

It must be numeric.  Looks like you've got some commas in there and R is considering it to be a factor or character type column.

Try

```
hist(table(mydata$V1))
```

or

```
barplot(table(mydata$V1))
```

to get a histogram of the resulting factor.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123378/how-to-read-in-numbers-with-a-comma-as-decimal-separator) if your goal is to read in the column as numeric, interpreting the comma as a decimal separator.

Comment: Matthew -- the commas are just the standard [decimal comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Countries_using_Arabic_numerals_with_decimal_comma) used in much of Europe as well as in many other parts of the world. If the correct region settings are used, R deals with that just fine; it's possible that's the issue, but other possibilities are more likely.

Comment: @Glen_b Wasn't aware of the region settings!  Definitely good to know.

Comment: Region settings may be the wrong word; you can however set up the options to mostly deal with input and output (numbers in commands are a bit tricky because `,` does something between numbers). See `options()$OutDec` which in your R session will be `"."`, but may be `","` in the OPs setup. There's also the possibility to set the decimal separator during reads and writes (the `dec` argument).

Answer (score 0):

Dont know why, but when I manualy imported data from dataset and changed encoding from automatic to UTF it works.