# ggplot2 remove tick markers from geom_bar facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can adjust y-tick labels for a geom_bar facet_wrap plot in ggplot2? I tried several options such as scale_y but didn't succeed ...

[Link to plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHkYu.jpg)

```
# Plot ---------------------------------------------------------------------
p <- ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data=uws, aes(y = Costs, x = Scenario, fill = Component), stat="identity",position='stack') + 
  ggtitle("Plot Title") +
  theme_bw() +  facet_wrap( ~ PE) # For facet choose between grid or wrap
```

The CSV file (uws) looks as follows:

```
> dput(uws)
structure(list(Scenario = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L), .Label = c("Conv", "S2", "S3", "S4"), class = "factor"), 
    Component = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("WWC", "WWT"), class = "factor"), 
    PE = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L), .Label = c("5,000", "10,000", "50,000", "100,000", 
    "500,000", "1,000,000", "1,500,000", "2,000,000", "2,500,000"
    ), class = "factor"), Costs = structure(c(28L, 61L, 1L, 45L, 
    18L, 38L, 34L, 4L, 54L, 7L, 1L, 62L, 39L, 52L, 59L, 12L, 
    29L, 33L, 1L, 24L, 19L, 16L, 36L, 1L, 56L, 49L, 1L, 43L, 
    40L, 27L, 57L, 60L, 30L, 14L, 1L, 11L, 20L, 2L, 35L, 22L, 
    55L, 26L, 1L, 25L, 41L, 9L, 58L, 31L, 5L, 32L, 1L, 37L, 51L, 
    15L, 6L, 44L, 8L, 42L, 1L, 46L, 63L, 21L, 10L, 48L, 13L, 
    47L, 1L, 50L, 3L, 23L, 17L, 53L), .Label = c("0", "100,877,653", 
    "1,161,742,099", "11,782,594", "1,184,976,941", "1,303,474,636", 
    "14,457,980", "1,579,969,255", "160,933,883", "1,737,966,181", 
    "182,380,189", "18,795,374", "1,974,961,569", "201,755,306", 
    "211,502,167", "21,379,682", "2,172,457,726", "2,323,484", 
    "23,234,842", "232,348,420", "256,752,017", "262,281,898", 
    "298,418,508", "30,393,724", "320,821,078", "321,867,765", 
    "34,105,538", "3,949,923", "39,499,231", "394,992,314", "418,428,095", 
    "423,004,335", "42,759,364", "4,344,915", "434,491,545", 
    "43,449,155", "449,044,916", "4,531,767", "4,646,968", "46,469,684", 
    "464,696,840", "513,504,035", "51,472,656", "549,905,635", 
    "5,617,335", "571,548,537", "596,837,015", "667,555,245", 
    "68,211,076", "690,195,107", "697,045,260", "7,228,990", 
    "775,888,120", "7,899,846", "789,984,628", "78,998,463", 
    "86,898,309", "868,983,090", "8,689,831", "88,674,399", "9,063,534", 
    "9,260,007", "929,393,680"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Scenario", 
"Component", "PE", "Costs"), row.names = c(NA, -72L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: this is well documented! and "data=uws" is not a reproducible example.

Comment: You definitely have a point here. I apologize and changed my post accordingly.

Comment: please use dput() for your reproducible example

Comment: How about [`theme`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html)?

Comment: @MLavoie - I changed my post. Is that what you meant with dput? I also added a picture of the plot

Comment: @RomanLuštrik - Thanks for your response. If I google for ggplot2 and theme I only find how to change scale-colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this what you want. Having access to your data was really useful.

if you look at the structure of your dataset, you will see that Cost is a factor. Just change it to numeric and it will work. it will easier to change your tick if still necessary

```
str(uws)
'data.frame':   72 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Scenario : Factor w/ 4 levels "Conv","S2","S3",..: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ...
 $ Component: Factor w/ 2 levels "WWC","WWT": 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ PE       : Factor w/ 9 levels "5,000","10,000",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ Costs    : Factor w/ 63 levels "0","100,877,653",..: 28 61 1 45 18 38 34 4 54 7 ...

p <- ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data=uws, aes(y = as.numeric(Costs), x = Scenario, fill = Component), stat="identity",position='stack') + 
  ggtitle("Plot Title") + ylab("Cost") +
  theme_bw() +  facet_wrap( ~ PE)
```

[image]

Comment: First of all thank you for your response! I was able to reproduce your graph (not too hard I admit).

But how can I get the actual costs on the y scale? I think now it's percentages, or not?

Comment: just remove the decimals from your cost, e.g.instead of 100,877,653, use 100877653, or take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123378/how-to-read-in-numbers-with-a-comma-as-decimal-separator

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried sep="" and dec="" in a few variations but somehow the column "PE" is not loaded properly anymore. All fields now say "NA" ... hence the graph is messed up. Any idea why this could be the case?

Comment: I removed this part
'uws$PE <- factor(uws$PE, levels = c("5,000", "10,000", "50,000", "100,000", "500,000", "1,000,000",  "1,500,000","2,000,000", "2,500,000"))' ... now it's working. Thanks for your help!