# Can not convert values from factor into only numeric

Tags: r

I want to convert this variable into numeric, as you can see:

```
> class(DATA$estimate)
[1] "factor"
> head(DATA$estimate)
[1] 0,253001909 0,006235543 0,005285019 0,009080499 6,580140903 0,603060006
57 Levels: 0,000263863 0,000634365 0,004405696 0,005285019 0,006235543 0,009080499 0,009700147 0,018568434 0,253001909 ... 7,790580873
>
```

But when I want to convert, look what I have got

```
> DATA$estimate<-as.numeric(DATA$estimate)
> DATA$estimate
 [1]  9  5  4  6 51 12  3 53 11  8  1  7 15 27 30 29 28 31 21 23 22 39 38 37 33 26 34 52 57 50 24 18 20 10  2 55 54 56 36 32 35 44 46
[44] 48 19 25 16 43 41 40 49 42 47 14 17 13 45
```

It's not numeric and I don't understand how the program gives these numbers!

Comment: This R joy. Try as.numeric(as.character(data$estimate))

Comment: Try first converting to factor and then to string

Comment: This is a common mistake that people make in R. You have to use `as.numeric(levels(DATA$estimate))[DATA$estimate]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a factor to integer\numeric without loss of information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information)

Comment: @A.Suliman, sorry doesn't work

Comment: @ANG, it gives `NA` values

Comment: Sure? It should work fine. Look at this: `v <- factor(c(0.253001909, 0.006235543, 0.005285019, 0.009080499,
              6.580140903, 0.603060006));
as.numeric(levels(v))[v]`. It should be good if you provide a reproducible example

Comment: @ANG you changed the OP input data. He does not have "." but ",".

Comment: @ANG both we refer to **R inferno/ CHIMERAS** and we were correct, but we forgot about ",".

Comment: How did you read the data? Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123378/how-to-read-in-numbers-with-a-comma-as-decimal-separator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

data:

```
fac <- factor(c("0,253001909" ,"0,006235543" ,"0,005285019" ,"0,009080499" ,"6,580140903" ,"0,603060006"))
```

I convert to character, then turn the "," into ".", then convert to numeric.

```
as.numeric(sub(",",".",as.character(fac)))
```

in your case its:

```
DATA$estimate<-as.numeric(sub(",",".",as.character(DATA$estimate)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also `scan()` your factor variable and specify `,` as decimal separator

```
fac <- factor(c("0,253001909" ,"0,006235543" ,"0,005285019" ,"0,009080499" ,
                "6,580140903" ,"0,603060006"))
scan(text = as.character(fac), dec = ",")
#output
[1] 0.253001909 0.006235543 0.005285019 0.009080499 6.580140903
[6] 0.603060006
```