# Data Cleaning using R Programming

Tags: r

I have Age  column in the data frame. Age is mentioned as 22,7 18,5 25,4
I need to replace , with decimal. How can I do that in R?

```
strsplit(as.character(age), ",")
[[1]]
[1] "22" "1" 

[[2]]
[1] "14" "7" 

[[3]]
[1] "19" "8" 

[[4]]
[1] "19" "7" 

[[5]]
[1] "22" "6" 

[[6]]
[1] "15" "7"
```

Comment: How did you read the data into R? We can set `dec` option, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123378/how-to-read-in-numbers-with-a-comma-as-decimal-separator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read in numbers with a comma as decimal separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123378/how-to-read-in-numbers-with-a-comma-as-decimal-separator)

Answer (score 3):

A way to replace the comma with a period is to use `scan` with argument `dec = ","`.

```
scan(text = "22,7 18,5 25,4", dec = ",")
#Read 3 items
#[1] 22.7 18.5 25.4


y <- c("22,7", "18,5", "25,4")

scan(textConnection(y), dec = ",")
#Read 3 items
#[1] 22.7 18.5 25.4
```

Comment: you can include `quiet=TRUE` within the scan function

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sub` to replace `,` with `.` and convert to `numeric`

```
as.numeric(sub(",", ".", age))
#[1] 22.7 18.5 25.4
```

---

Or with `chartr`

```
as.numeric(chartr(",", ".", age))
```

#### data

```
age <- c("22,7", "18,5", "25,4")
```

Comment: number$Age <- sub(",",".",number$Age) did the job for me. Thank you guys..!