# Comma separator ignored when reading in .csv files to R on a Spanish computer

Tags: r, csv, import, decimal, separator

I have a Spanish computer and am working in a French language environment, where the decimal separator is usually a comma.  I am more used to working with periods as decimal separators, so changed the separator in Microsoft Excel and also specified the separator when reading in the file to R as below:

```
eg <- read.csv("D:/02_COVID-19/Analysis/eglonglat.csv", dec = ".", sep = ",", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

However, it seems that the comma separator is being ignored, because the .csv has three columns and when read into R it has only one column.

I´m using a clean install of R 4.0 and RStudio 1.3.959 on a Windows 7 laptop.

Any ideas? I was only trying to copy some example data from a stack overflow post that used periods as decimal separators - not sure whether it is the intervention of excel that is causing the problem here (it looks like the decimal separators are periods but maybe they are not in the background?)

Here is what the output looks like in R after being read in:

```
> eg
            index.lat.lon
1    1;51.513393;-0.11565
2   2;51.513428;-0.115461
3   3;51.513428;-0.115462
4   4;51.513428;-0.115465
5    5;51.513428;-0.11547
6   6;51.513432;-0.115462
7   7;51.513432;-0.115467
8   8;51.513435;-0.115471
9   9;51.513439;-0.115468
10 10;51.513439;-0.115469
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `read.csv`, you need `sep = ";"` to separate columns and `dec = ","` to consider decimals with comma separator.

```
eg <- read.csv("D:/02_COVID-19/Analysis/eglonglat.csv", sep = ";", dec = ",")
```

These are default settings in `read.csv2`

```
eg <- read.csv2("D:/02_COVID-19/Analysis/eglonglat.csv")
```

Since you are on R 4.0.0, you don't need `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

---

Debugging further it seems OP has `"."` as decimal separator so this works :

```
eg <- read.csv("D:/02_COVID-19/Analysis/eglonglat.csv", sep = ";")
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip re `stringsAsFactors` good to know it is no longer converting to factor as the default...

Comment: @AmyM did the answer work? Looking at the output now i think you might need `eg <- read.csv("D:/02_COVID-19/Analysis/eglonglat.csv", sep = ";")`

Comment: They are now read in as three columns but the col class is character - wouldn´t this normally detect they are numeric?

Comment: you are right - not specifying the decimal separator seems to work (they are interpreted as numeric with the decimal separator in the right place)

Comment: Thanks to @akrun for directing to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123378/how-to-read-in-numbers-with-a-comma-as-decimal-separator) which explains that in countries that use the comma as a decimal separator, the .csv file column separator is actually a semi-colon, not a comma.  So even though I changed the decimal separator commas to periods, the column separator was still a semi-colon, which is handled by specifying `sep = ";"`with `read.csv`or using `read.csv2` instead where the semi-colon is the default column separator.