# Unable to produce histogram from simple dataset

Tags: r, histogram

I have the following simple dataset (a small section shown below) and want to produce a histogram from this using R studio (I am able to do this using Excel).

```
Samples   Number.of.OTUs
      A               13
      B               10
      C                9
      D                9
```

The dataset has been read in using the following command;

```
MD1 = read.csv("MD_qual_OTU_sorted_2.csv")
```

when I try to make a histogram I get this error

```
hist(MD1)
```

> Error in hist.default(MD1) : 'x' must be numeric

and this when I try `barplot`

```
barplot(MD1)
```

> Error in barplot.default(MD1) : 'height' must be a vector or a matrix

```
attributes(MD1)
# $names
# [1] "Samples"        "Number.of.OTUs"

# $class
# [1] "data.frame"

# $row.names
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
```

I know I could enter the data by hand in R but I want to be able to read in the CSV file preferably.

I have tried the solutions in the question marked as duplicate, but to no avail.

Comment: Side note: `barplot` and `hist` are totally different things.

Comment: Possible duplicate, e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349205/cant-draw-histogram-x-must-be-numeric

Comment: Thanks for that link Adrian, I did previously try  MD1= read.csv("MD_qual_OTU_sorted_2.csv", header= T, sep=",") and  MD1= read.csv("MD_qual_OTU_sorted_2.csv", header= T, dec=",") but with no joy :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the data I guess what you want is a barplot. 
The error you get is the result of a misspecification in the `barplot` command. 
The first argument (`height`) should be the `Number.of.OTUs` in your case, and you can specify the labels of the bars in the `names.arg` argument. 
What you're probably looking for is something like this:

```
MD1<-data.frame(Samples=c("A","B","C","D"), Number.of.OTUs=c(13,10,9,9))
par(las=1)  
barplot(MD1[,2],names.arg=MD1[,1])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect :)