# Using R- trying to plot frequency table

Tags: r, ggplot2

(1) i have a frequncy table called resdf that looks like this- [here is the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOjNM.png)

(2)this is the line of code i tried using
`awards_given<-hist(resdf$Year,resdf$Freq,type="h",breaks=seq(0,88,by=10))`

(3) i get this error

```
Error in hist.default(resdf$Year, resdf$Freq, type = "h", breaks = seq(0,  : 
  some 'x' not counted; maybe 'breaks' do not span range of 'x'
```

Comment: You can't plot 2 variables using ``hist()``.

Answer (score 0):

Histogram only takes a vector as input. You had put two in.
I guess this is what you want:

```
hist(resdf$Freq)
```

Comment: hi. i ran this line but it says now x must be numeric all coloumns are numeric in this df any other suggestions for this problem?

Comment: hi. i ran this line but it says now x must be numeric all coloumns are numeric in this df any other suggestions for this problem?

Comment: @CODERjack https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349205/cant-draw-histogram-x-must-be-numeric

Comment: Maybe your "Freq" column is not numeric? I have no idea on your data...
btw, you can try to coerce the variable to numeric :

hist(as.numeric(resdf$Freq))